# R: assign appropriate color to a vector of values from a defined user palette

Tags: r, numeric, color-palette

I have a numeric vector and a color palette like the ones below.

I do not want to make any kind of plot, the only thing I want is to assign the appropriate color to each numeric value, based on the palette...

The desired output would be a data frame that relates values to colors. Is there a simple way to do it?

```
my_palette <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"))(11)
my_vector <- c(runif(150,1,10))
my_df <- data.frame(value=my_vector, color=my_palette[1])


> head(my_df)
     value   color
1 4.029890 #00FF00
2 1.933029 #00FF00
3 4.921888 #00FF00
4 5.467826 #00FF00
5 9.232608 #00FF00
6 7.353821 #00FF00
```

Comment: Could you be explicit about the rules for assigning colours to numeric values? For example are you looking for something like values between 0-10 assigned red, >10-20 assigned blue etc.

Comment: Oh sorry! so the palette is from green to red so lower values should be green and higher red. The bottom and top limits aren't absolute, so just min() and max() of the numeric vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `cut`:

```
ncolors <- 11
my_palette <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"))(ncolors)

my_df <- data.frame(value=my_vector, color=my_palette[cut(my_vector,ncolors)])

head(my_df)

     value   color
1 1.289565 #00FF00
2 3.651295 #006500
3 4.750783 #003200
4 6.506106 #330000
5 5.615058 #000000
6 3.216121 #009900
```

Comment: can I change the number of breaks to 100 for example in an easy way (but stargint from the same my_palette)?

Comment: The number of cuts should be the number of colors of the palette : 1 cut per color

Comment: but is it possible to increase it in the cut step? cause if I do I get a lot of NA colors... it should be increased when generating the palette right?

Comment: right, you should increase the number of cuts in the palette beforehand

Answer (score 2):

A variation on the theme:

```r
my_palette <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"))(11)
set.seed(123)
my_vector <- c(runif(150,1,10))

my_df <- data.frame(value = my_vector,
                    color = cut(my_vector, 11, labels = my_palette))
head(my_df)
#>      value   color
#> 1 3.588198 #006500
#> 2 8.094746 #990000
#> 3 4.680792 #003200
#> 4 8.947157 #CC0000
#> 5 9.464206 #FF0000
#> 6 1.410008 #00FF00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You were certainly on a path that would take you there:

```r
library(spatstat)

set.seed( 100 )
my_palette <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(c("green","black","red"))(11)
my_vector <- c(runif(150,1,10))
cmap <- colourmap( my_palette, range=range(my_vector) )

my_df <- data.frame(value=my_vector, color= cmap( my_vector ) )
```

```
> head( my_df )
     value   color
1 3.769895 #006500
2 3.319053 #009900
3 5.970902 #330000
4 1.507448 #00FF00
5 5.216944 #000000
6 5.353937 #000000
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35045341/2165993)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `colorRampPalette`, you can use `colorRamp`, which returns a function that maps the interval [0,1] to colors.

```
myPalette <- colorRamp(c("green","black","red"))
```

Map your values to the interval [0,1]:

```
my_vector_normalized <- (my_vector - min(my_vector)) / (max(my_vector) - min(my_vector))
```

Then:

```
my_df <- data.frame(value = my_vector, color = myPalette(my_vector_normalized))
```

Comment: ah this is very relevant info! at the moment the palette is passed to my function in the form I wrote in the MWE, but I might consider changing it upstream